# Can I split Ext.toolbar.Toolbar in 2 columns

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Is there a way to split toolbar to 2 columns instead of 2 rows?
If someone asks what do I need this for, it's for the sake of usability.

Regards

Armando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to achieve this is to add two toolbars in my opinion.

I made a quick sencha fiddle for you: [Example app](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/39hq)

Comment: Ok good! Good thing I implemented this in the example aswell

Comment: toolbar item '->' does the trick ... good one